# Set buildTypes shows error Activity class does not exist

Tags: android, react-native

I want to set different environment on android with react native.

Step 1 create project:

Create a pure react native project `"react-native": "0.64.0",`

Step 2 add an environment releasestaging under android/app/build.gradle:

```
buildTypes{      
   //... 
    releasestaging {
            initWith release    
            applicationIdSuffix ".releasestaging" 
            matchingFallbacks =  ['release']
        }
  // ...
}
```

Step 3  type cpmmand on terminal:

```
npx react-native run-android --variant=releasestaging
```

build result shows the error:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
46 actionable tasks: 46 executed
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.testenvone/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.testenvone/com.testenvone.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Any one knows what step I miss ? Thanks.

Comment: Did you added MainActivity to the manifest file?

Comment: No, I just do step 1, 2, 3